# Can an index of lists post split function yielding index [[ ]] + S be converted to all [[

Tags: r

I have on one hand a vector of character elements F.

On another hand a set of functions which produces a segmented version of the two sublists in GF. The output SA produces a list with the desired segments, however the index of SA comes with the following format.

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`1` 
[[1]]$`2`    

[[2]]
[[2]]$`1`....   

F  <-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l") 

GF  <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) , c(2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1,3,4,5,2)) 
RET <- seq(length ( GF )) # SEQUENCE : NUMBER OF SUB-LISTS
LS  <- c( 3 , 2 ) # LENGTH OF EACH ADDITIONAL SUB-SUB SEGMENT WITHIN TWO LISTS
fun <- function (x) split ( GF[[x]] , ceiling (seq_along (GF[[x]])/LS[[x]]))
SA  <- (lapply (  RET  ,  fun )) # OUTPUT 
relist(unlist( F ), SA )
```

I would like to use the scheleton of SA as to relist F, however the index format acquired in output SA is a mix of [[ and S and would like it to be all [[.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by using unname within the split function

```
F  <-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l") 

GF  <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) , c(2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1,3,4,5,2)) 
RET <- seq(length ( GF )) # SEQUENCE : NUMBER OF SUB-LISTS
LS  <- c( 3 , 2 ) # LENGTH OF EACH ADDITIONAL SUB-SUB SEGMENT WITHIN TWO LISTS
fun <- function (x) unname(split ( GF[[x]] , ceiling (seq_along (GF[[x]])/LS[[x]])))
SA  <- (lapply (  RET  ,  fun )) # OUTPUT 
relist(unlist( F ), SA )
```

Comment: Appologies to all at the same time I was writing the question I was trying some alternatives and found the above answer to work fine.